# Placing a ListView together with a VideoView add several blank lines between them

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I created a page in Xamarin.Forms that should display some items, coming from an IList data source, and a video after them.

List of items will be displayed using ListView. The video is displayed using VideoView.

This is the actual page code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:mm="clr-namespace:Plugin.MediaManager.Forms;assembly=Plugin.MediaManager.Forms"
             x:Class="MyApp.Views.ItemDetailPage"
             Title="{Binding Title}">

    <ScrollView>
        <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" Padding="15">
            <ListView 
                ItemsSource="{Binding Item.Properties}"
                HasUnevenRows="true">
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ViewCell>
                            <StackLayout Padding="10">
                                <Label Text="{Binding .}" 
                                    LineBreakMode="NoWrap"
                                    Style="{DynamicResource ListItemTextStyle}" 
                                    FontSize="16" />
                            </StackLayout>
                        </ViewCell>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
            <mm:VideoView x:Name="MyVideo" WidthRequest="320" HeightRequest="190" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" />
            <Button x:Name="BtnPlayStop" Text="Iniciar" Clicked="PlayStop_Clicked" BackgroundColor="Silver" TextColor="White"/>
        </StackLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</ContentPage>
```

The problems I have when I run the app are:

1. The page initially appears scrolled down so that the video is initially seen.
2. The space between the last element of the list view and the video is very big
3. It´s difficult to do the scroll up or down by using the finger.

Is my XAML code correct? what changes can I apply to fix this weird behaviour?

EDIT: I have found that between the listview and video is nothing. That is why it is difficult to scroll. If I place the finger inside the list view, I can scroll, the same if I place the finger inside the video or button. But if I place the finger between the list view and the video no scroll is performed. Weird, isn't it?

Thanks
Jaime

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I have used solution in this page: https://xamarinsharp.com/2017/05/16/listview-height-issue-in-xamarin-forms-how-to-solve-it/

Basicly, it is to set the HeightRequest of the ListView in code behind according to the number of bound elements.

Regards

Jaime

Comment: Since the code in the link won't be visible if the website is down (say in a year or two), please explain the detailed solution here

Comment: That is why I explained basically what's the solution